# Tomcat 8.5 does not start as a service in a Windows environment within VMWare

Tags: vmware, tomcat

I have installed tomcat 8.5 on a windows machine inside a VMWare with OpenJDK11 from AdoptOpenJDK. When I start tomcat from command prompt the server starts up without any issues. However, when I start it as a service, it does not boot up.

The same combination of Tomcat and JDK works in my regular windows machine.

I looked at the tomcat logs by enabling debugging in tomcat.

```
[2019-09-15 06:29:47] [info]  [55156] Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.2.0.0 64-bit) started.
[2019-09-15 06:29:47] [info]  [55156] Running Service 'Tomcat8'...
[2019-09-15 06:29:47] [info]  [47588] Starting service...
```

Also, even if I start tomcat from command line as a service, it does not start.

```
    [2019-09-15 06:50:25] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1754) [61248] Apache Commons Daemon procrun log initialized.
    [2019-09-15 06:50:25] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1758) [61248] Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.2.0.0 64-bit) started.
    [2019-09-15 06:50:26] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1668) [61248] Running Service 'Tomcat8'...
    [2019-09-15 06:50:26] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1441) [53128] Inside ServiceMain...
    [2019-09-15 06:50:26] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:904 ) [53128] reportServiceStatusE: dwCurrentState = 2, dwWin32ExitCode = 0, dwWaitHint = 3000, dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0.
    [2019-09-15 06:50:26] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1196) [53128] Starting service...
```

I could be wrong but could it be something to do with VMWare architecture and Tomcat recognizing wrong native libs.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit JVM?

Comment: @MarkThomas Its a a 64 bit JVM and Windows 7 64 bit.
Just to reiterate it works from command line if I run startup.bat.
However, does not start as a service both from the manager and from the command line.

Comment: Check all the log files for errors. Anything?

Comment: Did check. no logs except the ones posted here.

Comment: Tomcat version?